# Looping through a numpy matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, matrix

Why doesn't the following code work?

```
import numpy

grid = numpy.matrix([[1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,0],[1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]])
i = 0
for line in grid:
    for block in line:
        if block == 1:
            i += 1    
print("Grid has " + str(i) + " times number 1")
```

I thought it's gonna first cycle through every line and then every element  of the line and compare it with 1, but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 7, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is 
ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: If you had used `numpy.array` instead of `numpy.matrix`, you wouldn't have had this problem. Seriously, `numpy.matrix` isn't worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating through a `numpy.matrix` matrix produces 1-row `numpy.matrix` matrices, one for each row.

Iterating over a 1-row `numpy.matrix` matrix produces a 1-row `numpy.matrix` matrix, not the individual cells.

Don't use `numpy.matrix`. It's not at all worth it. Also, don't loop over NumPy objects at all if you can help it:

```
grid = numpy.array([[1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,0],[1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]])
i = grid.sum()
```